# Error setting home directory when using python-gnupg

Tags: python

I just installed python-gnupg (with "pip install python-gnupg" witn a Conda terminal); I installed it both on the base environment and also on the environment I'm running) and I'm trying to generate a key. I'm following instructions from https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/#before-you-start

My code is this:

```
import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Python_projects/')
gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
input_data = gpg.gen_key_input(key_type="RSA",
                               key_length=1024)
key =gpg.gen_key(input_data)

print(key)
```

However, I get this error message:

> runfile('C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Python_projects/Canvas/Canvas 18.py',
> wdir='C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Python_projects/Canvas',
> current_namespace=True) Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\Users\danil\anaconda3\envs\spyder-5.2.2\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py",
> line 881, in **init**
> p = self._open_subprocess(["--version"])
>
> File
> "C:\Users\danil\anaconda3\envs\spyder-5.2.2\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py",
> line 961, in _open_subprocess
> result = Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
>
> File
> "C:\Users\danil\anaconda3\envs\spyder-5.2.2\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in **init**
> super(SubprocessPopen, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\danil\anaconda3\envs\spyder-5.2.2\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 951, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>
> File "C:\Users\danil\anaconda3\envs\spyder-5.2.2\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1420, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
> specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\danil\OneDrive\Python_projects\Canvas\Canvas 18.py",
> line 6, in 
> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='C:/Users/danil/OneDrive/Python_projects')
>
> File
> "C:\Users\danil\anaconda3\envs\spyder-5.2.2\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py",
> line 885, in **init**
> raise OSError(msg)
>
> OSError: Unable to run gpg (gpg) - it may not be available.

The directory specified exists. I tried different ways of passing the directory (e.g., 'C:\Users\danil\OneDrive\Python') but it didn't work. It appears to start with a "fine not found" issue. I'm using a Windows 10 machine - so I checked for some sort of restricted access for Windows Defender but didn't see any new allerts.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

Accorindg to [python-gnupg home page](https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/)

> Apart from a recent-enough version of Python, in order to use this
> module you need to have access to a compatible version of the GnuPG
> executable. The system has been tested with GnuPG v1.4.9 on Windows
> and Ubuntu. On a Linux platform, this will typically be installed via
> your distribution’s package manager (e.g. `apt-get` on Debian/Ubuntu).
> Windows binaries are available [here](ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/) – use one of the
> `gnupg-w32cli-1.4.x.exe` installers for the simplest deployment
> options.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Daweo for pointing me in the right direction. Here are a few details on how to install the correct .exe file:

- Go to the official project website: https://www.gnupg.org/index.html
- Click on Downloads
- Scroll down to "GnuPG binary releases"
- Download the "Simple installer for the current GnuPG" - when I did so, I got the file "GnuPG-w32-2.3.4_20211220.exe". This should be sufficient for most needs.
- If you scroll down a little further in the page you will see a list with "End-of-life announcements" - note that the 1.4 version is a legacy version. For most people, I believe they are looking for the latest version available.

After I downloaded the .exe file and installed it on my Windows 10 machine, everything works seamlessly.

Since some of the examples I found online were not fully complete, I decided to share below a series of tests. I hope it helps some beginners. I now can receive an encrypted .csv file (encrypted with a public key I generated) and decrypt it, which was my objective.

The sample code:

```
# GPG key pair generation and encryption and decryption
# Some usefull reference:
# https://docs.red-dove.com/python-gnupg/
# https://www.gnupg.org/index.html

gpg_path = 'C:/Users/username/GPG_keys/' # the folder you want to work with

#%% generate key

import gnupg

gen_key = False # set to true to generate key; included to avoid generating multiple keys when pressing F5 accidentaly

if gen_key:
    
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_path)
    #gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
    input_data = gpg.gen_key_input(key_type = "RSA",
                                   key_length = 2048,
                                   expire_date = 0,
                                   passphrase = 'your_pass_phrase',
                                   name_real = 'Your Name Here',
                                   name_email = 'your_email@domain.com')
    key = gpg.gen_key(input_data)
    
    print('Key fingerprint: '+ str(key))


#%% list keys

import gnupg
from pprint import pprint

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_path)
public_keys = gpg.list_keys()
private_keys = gpg.list_keys(secret=True)
print ('public keys:')
pprint(public_keys)
print ('private keys:')
pprint(private_keys)


#%% export key to asc file; in this case export the first key read above

ascii_public_keys = gpg.export_keys(public_keys[0]['keyid'])
ascii_private_keys = gpg.export_keys(private_keys[0]['keyid'], secret=True, passphrase='your_pass_phrase')
with open(gpg_path+'mykeyfile.asc', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ascii_public_keys)
    f.write(ascii_private_keys)


#%% import keys

import gnupg
from pprint import pprint

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_path)
key_data = open(gpg_path+'mykeyfile.asc').read()
import_result = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
pprint(import_result.results)


#%% deleting a key

delete_key = False # set to True to delete a specific key

if delete_key:
    fp = '563E115BB1BA5FA76FDEC1A48AA909D50093CAA7' # fingerprint of key to be deleted
    str(gpg.delete_keys(fp, secret=True, passphrase='your_pass_phrase')) # must delete private key first
    str(gpg.delete_keys(fp))


#%% encrypt text

data = 'test 123, test 123'
fp =  '563E115BB1BA5FA76FDEC1A48AA909D50093CAA7' # fingerprint of key to be used
encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt(data, fp)
print("Test data: " + data + '\n')
print (encrypted_ascii_data)


#%% decrypt text

print('Data received: ' + str(encrypted_ascii_data))
decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt(encrypted_ascii_data.data, passphrase='your_pass_phrase')
print ('Decrypted data: ' + str(decrypted_data))


#%% encrypt a file

filename = gpg_path + 'original_test_file.csv' # test .csv file you want to use
stream = open(filename, 'rb')
encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt_file(stream, fp)
with open(gpg_path+'ascii_test_file.asc', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(encrypted_ascii_data))


#%% decrypt a file

filename = gpg_path + 'ascii_test_file.asc'
stream = open(filename, 'rb')
decrypted_file_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream, passphrase='your_pass_phrase')
with open(gpg_path+'decrypted_test_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write(str(decrypted_file_data))
```

Answer (score -1):

Has this code worked. I am not able to run this from aws lambda.
{"message":"Exception_Message : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'"

["File : /var/task/lambda_function.py , Line : 24, Func.Name : lambda_handler, Message : gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='/mnt/tmp/gnupg_home/.gnupg', binary='/mnt/tmp/python/gpg', verbose=False)", 'File : /opt/python/gnupg/gnupg.py , Line : 162, Func.Name : **init**, Message : self.create_trustdb()', 'File : /opt/python/gnupg/gnupg.py , Line : 172, Func.Name : create_trustdb, Message : if self.is_gpg2():', 'File : /opt/python/gnupg/gnupg.py , Line : 212, Func.Name : is_gpg2, Message : return _util._is_gpg2(self.binary_version)', 'File : /opt/python/gnupg/_util.py , Line : 531, Func.Name : _is_gpg2, Message : (major, minor, micro) = _match_version_string(version)', 'File : /opt/python/gnupg/_util.py , Line : 617, Func.Name : _match_version_string, Message : g = matched.groups()']

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).